# Get a value back from the MVC view outside of the model

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have a Create view that displays a value along with the form. When they submit I would like to also have that value available.

In my Controller I have this:

```
public ActionResult Create(Guid? id)
{
    if (id == null || id == Guid.Empty) return View();
    ViewBag.RegistrationVerificationId = id; 
    var email = (from rv in _db.RegistrationVerification
                 where rv.RegistrationVerificationId == id
                 select rv.Email).FirstOrDefault();
    ViewBag.Email = email;
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Create(Profile profileModel)
{
    if (ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        var emailValue = @ViewBag.Email;
        //...
    }
    //...
 }
```

My View looks like this:

```
@model PublicationSystem.Model.Profile
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Create";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

@using (Html.BeginForm()) 
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-horizontal">
        <h4>Profile</h4>
        <hr />
        @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

        @Html.HiddenFor(model => model.ProfileId)
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.Label("Email Provided", htmlAttributes: new {@class = "control-label col-md-2"})
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @ViewBag.Email
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Salutation, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Salutation)
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Salutation)
            </div>
        </div>
        ....
}
```

What is the best way to store the value between Response and Postback?

Comment: That value can be changed by user? If not, the best option is to get it back inside the controller, so the user cannot change it with *Inspect Element*

Comment: However, if you still want to do it... You can set an Hidden field so that the field is passed to controller

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Session["email"] = email;
```

This will store the value between response and postback. Let me know if this is what you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**TempData** can work for you. Another option is to store it in hidden field and receive it back on POST but you should be aware that "bad users" can modify that (via browser developer tools for example).

Answer (score 0):

**If you need values that were rendered with the view to arrive in the POST**

You should add that value to the Model (`Profile` in your case).

**If you need values that were saved with POST to load in the next view**

If you are using the same action (`return View()`), just preload the model.

```
DoStuff();
return View(new Model { MyValue = "foo" });
```

If you are redirecting to another action, use persisted state, and redirect using appropriate route parameters.

```
var transactionId = SaveThings();
return RedirectToAction("Confirmation", new {transactionId});
```

And load the values you need depending on how you persisted the information. If the information is OK to stick in route parameters, even simpler.